# Setting WEAK to a non @property variable

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, automatic-ref-counting, weak

Will need someone with knowledge of ARC to help me.

Basically, I have declared some variables as such in my class

```
@interface Class{
    NSString* one;
    NSString* two;
}

@property(nonatomic,weak) NSString* one;
```

As you can see, I can set the weak identifier to `NSString* one`. However, I do not need a getter/setter/synthesizer for `NSString* two` as it is just a common variable. How can I set a `weak` label to it so the memory is deallocated? Or is automatically set?

Answer (score 5):

You *can* do it like this:

```
__weak NSString *two;
```

But you probably do not *want* to do it in this case.

Declaring an instance variable `__weak` means that the reference to the target object (a string in your case) will exist only as long as some other object holds a reference. When the last object holding a strong reference releases the string, your variable `two` will get `nil`-ed out automatically. This is very useful when objects hold references to each other, such as in parent-child hierarchies. Since your `NSString *two` could not possibly hold a reference to your object, using the `__weak` reference for it is highly questionable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without worrying:

```
NSString* two = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

When your instance of the class `Class` is release for some reason, since is the only one (in theory) referencing `two`, it will be deallocated.

Answer (score 0):

My advice (and I think Apple's although I could be wrong) would be to get into the habit of always using properties for your iVars, then this problem goes away.